# optimizing a slow postgresql query against multiple tables

Tags: postgresql

One of our PostgreSQL queries started getting slow (~15 seconds) so we looked at migrating to a Graph database.  Early tests show significantly faster speeds, so AWESOME.

Here's the problem- we still need to store a backup of the data in Postgres for non-analytics needs.  The Graph database is just for analytics, and we'd prefer for it to remain a secondary data store.  Because our business logic changed quite a bit during this migration, two existing tables turned into 4 -- and the current 'backup' selects in Postgres take anywhere from 1 to 6 minutes to run.

I've tried a few ways to optimize this, and the best seems to be turning this into two queries.  If anyone can suggest obvious mistakes here , I'd love to hear a suggestion.  I've tried switching up left/right/inner joins with little difference in the query planner.  The join order does affect a difference ; I think I'm just not getting this correctly.

I'll go into details.

Goal : Retrieve the last 10 attachments sent to a given person

Database Structure :

```
CREATE TABLE message ( 
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL , 
    body_raw TEXT 
    );
CREATE TABLE attachments ( 
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL , 
    body_raw TEXT 
    );
CREATE TABLE message_2_attachments ( 
    message_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES message(id) , 
    attachment_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES attachments(id) 
    );

CREATE TABLE mailings ( 
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL , 
    event_timestamp TIMESTAMP not null , 
    recipient_id INT NOT NULL  , 
    message_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES message(id) 
    );
```

sidenote: the reason why a mailing is abstracted from the message is that a mailing often has more than one recipient /and/ a single message can go out to multiple recipients

This query takes about 5 minutes on a relatively small dataset (query planner time is the comment above each item ) :

```
-- 159374.75
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT attachments.*
FROM attachments
JOIN message_2_attachments ON attachments.id = message_2_attachments.attachment_id
JOIN message ON message_2_attachments.message_id = message.id
JOIN mailings ON mailings.message_id = message.id
WHERE mailings.recipient_id = 1
ORDER BY mailings.event_timestamp desc limit 10 ;
```

Splitting it up into 2 queries only takes 1/8 the time :

```
-- 19123.22
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT message_2_attachments.attachment_id
FROM mailings
JOIN message ON mailings.message_id = message.id
JOIN message_2_attachments ON message.id = message_2_attachments.message_id
JOIN attachments ON message_2_attachments.attachment_id = attachments.id
WHERE mailings.recipient_id = 1
ORDER BY mailings.event_timestamp desc limit 10 ;

-- 1.089
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM attachments WHERE id IN ( results of above query )
```

I've tried re-writing the queries a handful of times -- different join orders, different types of joins, etc.  I can't seem to make this anywhere nearly as efficient in a single query as it can be in two.

*UPDATED* Github has better formatting, so the full output of explain is here - https://gist.github.com/jvanasco/bc1dd38ca06e52c9a090

Comment: Can you post the output of the EXPLAIN as well?

Comment: Thanks.  I added it to a github gist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugged in the output of your explain here : http://explain.depesz.com/s/hqPT

As you can see, the :

```
Hash Join  (cost=96588.85..158413.71 rows=44473 width=3201) (actual time=22590.630..30761.213 rows=44292 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (message_2_attachment.attachment_id = attachment.id)
```

is taking a good amount of time. I'd try to add indexes to the foreign keys as well with :

```
CREATE INDEX idx_message_2_attachments_attachment_id ON "message_2_attachments" USING btree (attachment_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_message_2_attachments_message_id ON "message_2_attachments" USING btree (message_id);`
CREATE INDEX idx_mailings_message_id ON "mailings" USING btree (message_id);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't think indexes would have much of an impact, because the table structure itself is so standardized. Adding those indexes didn't make much of a difference, but this made a HUGE difference "CREATE INDEX "idx_mailings_message_speedy" ON "mailings" USING btree (event_timestamp);"

Comment: What does the explain look like now? I _love_ seeing the "after".

Comment: i'll pull it later, but the 2:30s queries are now 100ms.  the event_timestamp index dropped it down to 200ms; your 3 indexes dropped it down to 100ms.    without the event_timestamp index, i think it was around 20 seconds.

Comment: I'd guess that the index is allowing the query to be driven from the mailings table in event_timestamp desc order, with nested loop joins to the other tables that halt when 10 rows are found.

Answer (score 0):

The junction table is missing a primary key. Also it is advisable to add a *reversed* index on this PK:

```
CREATE TABLE message_2_attachments (
    message_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES message(id) ,
    attachment_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES attachments(id)
        , PRIMARY KEY (message_id,attachment_id) -- <<== here
    );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON message_2_attachments(attachment_id,message_id); -- <<== here
```

For the mailings table, the situation is not so clear. It *looks like* some combination of {event_timestamp, recipient_id, message_id} could function as a candidate key. The `id` field merely functions as a surrogate.